# Rails Select in Form returns Index. I want to send the Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, text, indexing

```
<%= f.select :owner, options_for_select(names) %>
```

Here names is an array of names e.g. "harry", "barry", "joe".
The form element sets value of :owner to the index of the selected option i.e. 0,1,2.
I want to send the value instead i.e. "harry", "barry", "joe".

Is there an option for select that will do so? If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Map name in a [two element array of [text,value] pairs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) thus:

```
<%= f.select :owner, options_for_select(names.map {|name| [name,name]}) %>
```