# Why does Rails pass "0" from a select statement to ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, select, activerecord

I have been working on this for 2 hours and still have found no solution or any reasoning to why this is happening.

in my model I have

```
models/course.rb

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates! :province, inclusion: { :in => ['Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','New Brunswick','Newfoundland and Labrador','Nova Scotia','Ontario','Prince Edward Island','Quebec','Saskatchewan', 'Province'], message: "%{value} is not included in the list" }
end
```

in my view I have this select statement

```
= form_for @course, url: teach_path do |f|
  = f.select :province, options_for_select(['Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','New Brunswick','Newfoundland and Labrador','Nova Scotia','Ontario','Prince Edward Island','Quebec','Saskatchewan'], "#{@course.province.to_s}"), {include_blank: "Choose your Province"}, {required: :required}
  = f.submit
```

However when I submit the form I get this error:

```
ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed in CoursesController#create
Province 0 is not included in the list
```

I have tried even defining my own method in the active record model

```
def includes_province
  unless ['Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','New Brunswick','Newfoundland and Labrador','Nova Scotia','Ontario','Prince Edward Island','Quebec','Saskatchewan', 'Province'].include?(province.to_s)
    errors.add(:base, "There is no #{province} in the list")
  end
end
```

It just returns

```
There is no 0 in the list
```

Why is province always 0 no matter what? I have checked the logs and it shows:

```
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "course"=>{"province"=>"Manitoba"}, "commit"=>"submit"}
```

Comment: what is the field type for province in the schema.rb

Comment: It seems province is integer type in table?

Comment: I think that is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668302/rails-select-in-form-returns-index-i-want-to-send-the-text

Comment: Please ensure that the datatype of the `province` column in your `courses` table in the database is `string` (aka `VARCHAR(255)`) and not `integer`.

Comment: Oh crap you are right, it is set as integer! I forgot I wanted to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as @spickermann says ensure your province field is not Integer in DB. Check migration that create Course table (something like CreateCourses) in rails_app/db/migrate folder, or simply check schema.rb file under rails_app/db/ folder. Check whether it says

```
t.integer :province
```

If so, your column is interger and by assigning it a string (any string) it would actually set 0 to integer value.
To replicate same thing, try calling "rails console" (or "rails c") in your OS command line and then typing

```
c = Course.take # takes random course from db and loads it to c var
c.province = "Manitoba" # assign string value to the field - like it happens in form
c.province # will actually print 0 !
```

Once you change column type to t.string instead of i.integer it should work.